# DisplacementFilter fails in mobile mode

Tags: vue.js, pixi.js

Hi I'm using pixi's built in displacement filter (PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter). It works perfectly in desktop mode. The problem is, when I load the page in mobile mode the DisplacementFilter doesn't work. It might have soemthing to do with buffering. I'm at a loss.
Thanks for your help.

Here's what I'm using :
vue js : 2.6.12
pixi js : 6.3.0
Mobile browser : chrome 104.0.5112.97
desktop browser : chrome 104.0.5112.102

Comment: try reporting this in: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues . Please also describe your device etc. If you can provide working example on https://www.pixiplayground.com/ then it would be perfect

Comment: I managed to find a solution : When setting scale instead of width and height of the displacement map sprite it works in both modes, desktop and mobile. I'm using quiet a large texture for the map and the sprite maybe didn't scale properly when toggeling desktop/mobile mode.